# What does "sweet pieties" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the bold part? Is it about insincerity?

"There are those who, under the influence of theoretical preconceptions, regard the human values expressed in architecture esthetically irrelevant, a mere unavoidable concession to utility. That buildings are esthetically the worse because they express the pomp of power, the majesty of government, **the sweet pieties of domestic relations,** the busy traffic of cities, and the adoration of worshipers is not apparent." - Art as Experience, John Dewey

Comment: The usage has no real currency. It's a facetious format, [modelled on ***sweet nothings.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sweet+nothings%2Csweet+pieties&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csweet%20nothings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csweet%20pieties%3B%2Cc0) It just means *[pleasant-sounding] pious utterances* with the strong implication that the piety is insincere, and the utterances aren't really of any significance. Where ***...of domestic relations*** implies ***being "nice" to your life-partner***.

Comment: In short, *the sweet pieties of domestic relations* pretty much amounts to what's represented by a plaque in the "happy home" saying something like ***Home is where the heart is*** or ***Home Sweet Home*** (or perhaps ***God bless this house*** for the more religion-oriented). A real "picture of domestic bliss" as they say.

Comment: Thank you very much.